# Regex to match a line with a specific word BEFORE a target word

Tags: python, regex

I am a total noob and want to write a regex in python where I can match the **line** containing "fruits" using only the word "orange". There is an unknown number of lines between "fruits" and "orange".

This is as far as I've gotten:

((^.*\b(fruits)\b.*$(\n|\r|\r\n)))orange

```
my colors
 i am red
 i am blue
 i am green

my fruits
 abc
 def
 i am a apple
 i am a orange
 i am a banana
 

my vehicle
 i am a sedan
 i am a van
 i am a motorbike
```

should match the line

```
my fruits
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So you want to match this kind of formatted list containing "orange" and then get the 1st line?

Comment: The line "my fruits"

Comment: That did not answer my specific question in any shape or form. Is this what you need? https://regex101.com/r/vMW5w3/1

Comment: I realize my regex does not make any sense because the idea is I ONLY know the word "orange" but need to match the entire line "my fruits" WITHOUT knowing the word "fruits". All I know is the word "my" so I need to use "my" as a keyword to return the whole line "my fruits". Sorry I know it's confusing, does that make sense? Thank you

Comment: Nope. I'm voting to close this for lack of clarity as you described that the line contains `fruits` in your question, which is the opposite to your comment. I'd recommend to start being more accurate and editing the question to **very accurately** state what you need as it has 3/5 close votes atm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use groups. Refer to this example (quick and dirty, no error handling in case no match...)

```python
import re

text="""
my colors
 i am red
 i am blue
 i am green

my fruits
 abc
 def
 i am a apple
 i am a orange
 i am a banana
 

my vehicle
 i am a sedan
 i am a van
 i am a motorbike
 """
 

res=re.search(r'\n*(my [a-zA-Z]*)\n([a-zA-Z ]+\n)*.*orange.*',text)

print(res.group(1))
```

This returns "my fruits". Please note, this works only for the specific example, since you don't have accurately specified the format of the input pattern.